# Call to undefined method stdClass::delete() in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

What is wrong in this syntax :

```
$cprefdel = DB::table('cprefs')
  ->where('user_id', $user_id)
  ->get();



foreach($cprefdel as $cprefdels){
    $cprefdels->delete();
}   

exit;
```

I'm receiving this error :

```
Call to undefined method stdClass::delete()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Eloquent in order to use [delete model method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#deleting-models).

*//Supposing your model name is Cpref for cprefs table*

```
use App\Cpref;

$cprefdel = Cpref::where('user_id', $user_id)
  ->get();


//Now you can use delete model method
foreach($cprefdel as $cprefdels){
    $cprefdels->delete();
}
```

You can also delete without using foreach loop like

```
$cprefdel = Cpref::where('user_id', $user_id)
  ->delete();
```

Comment: This causes a major overhead because it loops through every result and runs a single query to delete it. This would result in 1000 queries voor 1000 records instead of 1 query for 1000 records in my solution

Comment: Yes keeping in mind about the query optimization. I have added the optimized way below.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code if you have `Cpref` model class.

```
$cprefdel = Cpref::where('user_id', $user_id)
  ->get();

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following with Query Builder:

> DB::table('cprefs')->where('user_id', $user_id)->delete();

Or for specific id,

> DB::table('cprefs')->delete($user_id);

Tested in Laravel 5.8